# How to build target B which depends on target A's execution and output

Tags: cmake

Given a CMake target A and target B, where B depends on A and A is a preprocessor for code belonging to B.
I am trying to get the following behaviour:

A is built, executed and its standard output is used to write out define C preprocessor directives/macros
which need to be forwarded to B's building description through target_compile_definitions(...)

I have tried adding an intermediary custom target, pre-B, which calls A's program and stores its output.

```
add_custom_target(
    pre-B
    COMMAND A OUTPUT_VARIABLE DEFS
)
# pre-B executable outputs C preprocessor definitions into DEFS

target_compile_definitions(B PRIVATE  ${DEFS})

add_dependencies(B pre-B)
```

I believe the problem with this is that when I call target_compile_definitions with ${DEFS} as an argument, it is empty at the time of evaluation which leads to my question.

How can I define compile definitions for target B when they arrive from the output of executing target A?
(CMake 3.0+)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can generate a file containing the defs instead and have the possibility to add an `#include(defs.h)` in target B sources I would recommend to use `add_custom_command()` instead.

> A target created in the same directory (CMakeLists.txt file) that specifies any output of the custom command as a source file is given a rule to generate the file using the command at build time.

src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#generating-files

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT DEFS
  COMMAND ....)

add_library(B ... ${DEFS})
```

According to the doc of `add_custom_target()`

> The target has no output file and is always considered out of date even if the commands try to create a file with the name of the target. Use the add_custom_command() command to generate a file with dependencies.

src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `execute_process()` instead.

```
execute_process(
  COMMAND A
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE DEFS
)
```

> Both commands run while CMake is processing the project prior to build system generation. Use add_custom_target() and add_custom_command() to create custom commands that run at build time.

src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html